# Give an opinion about an object was done in the past

Tags: sentence-construction, past-tense

When I see an object, a person or a draw and I want to tell it for someone, What should I say?

> I saw a very cool graffiti on the train.
>   I have seen a very cool graffiti on the train.

I think which both are corrects, but to be more exact when to use `Simple Past` I should detail with "words" that will give me more time precision, for instance:

`Yesterday, Last week ..`

Comment: Only temporal expressions which **include the present** can be used with the present perfect. You can say "I have seen it *this week*", but you must say "I saw it *last week*". -- And by the way, most adjectives precede the noun they modify, unless they have a following complement: "I saw a very cool graffiti on the train."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In colloquial usage, "Yesterday, I saw very cool graffiti" and "Last week, I saw very cool graffiti" would be most common, with "I have seen very cool graffiti" being used to imply you once saw it, but at a unspecified time in the past.

(side note: graffiti is already plural, so it would never have an 'a' in front of it, but 'the graffiti' is acceptable. Also, unlike in many other languages, adjectives typically go before the noun in English.)